# Several relationships in one model in Laravel

Tags: laravel, orm, relationship

How can I save a model with two relationships in Laravel?

I have 3 model:

```
Model user:

    id
    name

Model post:

    id
    text
    user_id

Model comment:

    id
    message
    post_id
    user_id
```

Create comment:

```
#find post
$post = Post::find(1);

#Create comment and connect to post 
$comment = $post->comments()->create($validated);

#How connect user?
```

How connect user?

There are many examples in the documentation, but nothing like this.

Comment: There is an error in this line: $comment = $post->comments()->create($validated) because the  no user in $validated

Comment: `$validated['user_id'] = auth()->id()`

Comment: I try this, have error: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneOrMany::create(): Argument #1 ($attributes) must be of type array, int given, called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While `$model->relation()->create([])` creates a related model, in the context of the relation, there isn't a way to give multiple contexts for multiple relations.
So you need to add the `user_id` yourself the data passed to `create`

```php
#find post
$validated = $request->validated();
$validated['user_id'] = $request->user()->id; // user performing the request
$post = Post::find(1);

#Create comment and connect to post 
$comment = $post->comments()->create($validated);
```

Comment: have error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 NOT NULL constraint failed: comments.user_id

Comment: add in to protectde $fillable and it`s work. Thank you!